# Using jquery.validate.js to Validate WebForms when using in multiple Usercontrols

Tags: asp.net, jquery-validate

So I have a Default Search page that calls 2 UserControls

```
<uc1:BasicSearch ID="BasicSearch" runat="server" />
<uc1:AdvancedSearch ID="AdvancedSearch" runat="server" />
```

Both of my usercontrols have multiple date Fields that I wish to validate but I'm having a few issues

1. Since I'm using .net, the Controls get renamed, I got around this but using <%=specificDateTextbox.UniqueID%>, however, this ONLY works in the page, once I try to move all the Script to a .JS page it stops working.
2. For some reason, the validation never fires on the AdvancedSearch control when both are loaded.  If I comment out the BasicSearch usercontrol, the AdvancedSearch validation fires as it should.

This obviously leads me to believe there's a naming conflict or perhaps I can only use a sinlge validation script on a a page?

The code im using

BasicSearch.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="specificDateTextbox" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"></asp:TextBox>
```

The Script

```
<script>

    $(function () {

        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                <%=specificDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: {
                    dateISO:true,                        
                },
                <%=RangeStartDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: {
                    dateISO:true,                        
                },
                <%=RangeEndDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: {
                    dateISO:true                        
                }
            },
            messages: 
                {  
                    <%=specificDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)",
                    <%=RangeStartDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)",
                    <%=RangeEndDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)"    
                },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-horizontal').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.form-horizontal').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            errorElement: 'span',
            errorClass: 'help-block',
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });

    }); 


</script>
```

AdvancedSearch.ascx

> 

The Script

```
<script>

    $(function () {

            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    <%=AdvSpecificDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: {
                        dateISO:true                        
                    }
                },
                messages: 
                    {  
                        <%=AdvSpecificDateTextbox.UniqueID%>: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)"
                    },
                highlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-horizontal').addClass('has-error');
                },
                unhighlight: function (element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-horizontal').removeClass('has-error');
                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'help-block',
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                }
            });

        }); 


    </script>
```

**Edit**
The two rendered controls look like the below

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$BasicSearch$specificDateTextbox" type="text" id="MainContent_BasicSearch_specificDateTextbox" class="form-control " placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />   

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$AdvancedSearch$AdvSpecificDateTextbox" type="text" id="MainContent_AdvancedSearch_AdvSpecificDateTextbox" class="form-control " placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To troubleshoot what's going wrong, we'd need to see the relevant markup as it's being rendered in the browser source.  Once the problem is identified, you can fix your server-side code to render the proper markup.

Comment: Part of your issue might be a lack of understanding about how this plugin works.  Rules are identified within `.validate()` by the `name`, not their `id`.  Again, you can only verify what's actually happening by looking at the ***rendered*** code.

Comment: I've updated my question.  I can see that both the ID and name are being prefixed.  If necessary, I don't mind refering to the Rendered control in the JS.

Comment: Well, it's not like you have a choice here.  It's JavaScript, which runs in the browser and only cares about the rendered code.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that i HAVE to use the fully rendered name?

Comment: Yes, how else can the JavaScript work?  It runs in the browser so it only sees/knows whatever code is rendered in the browser.  [Refer to tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).   You also never showed us how your `.validate()` is rendered in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I was able to make the validator work with usercontrols by using the fully rendered control name and chaining the rules together in a .js for the page that calls the user controls.

see below

search.aspx

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="BasicSearch" Src="~/_usercontrols/BasicSearch.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="AdvancedSearch" Src="~/_usercontrols/AdvancedSearch.ascx" %>
<uc1:BasicSearch ID="BasicSearch" runat="server" />
<uc1:AdvancedSearch ID="AdvancedSearch" runat="server" />  
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/scripts/search/_actions.js")%>"></script>
```

_actions.js

$(function () {

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        ctl00$MainContent$BasicSearch$specificDateTextbox: {
            dateISO: true
        },
        ctl00$MainContent$BasicSearch$RangeStartDateTextbox: {
            dateISO: true
        },
        ctl00$MainContent$BasicSearch$RangeEndDateTextbox: {
            dateISO: true
        },
        ctl00$MainContent$AdvancedSearch$AdvSpecificDateTextbox: {
            dateISO: true
        },
        ctl00$MainContent$AdvancedSearch$AdvRangeStartDateTextbox: {
            dateISO: true
        },
        ctl00$MainContent$AdvancedSearch$AdvRangeStartEndTextbox: {
            dateISO: true
        }
    },
    messages:
        {
            ctl00$MainContent$BasicSearch$specificDateTextbox: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)",
            ctl00$MainContent$BasicSearch$RangeStartDateTextbox: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)",
            ctl00$MainContent$BasicSearch$RangeEndDateTextbox: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)",
            ctl00$MainContent$AdvancedSearch$AdvSpecificDateTextbox: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)",
            ctl00$MainContent$AdvancedSearch$AdvRangeStartDateTextbox: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)",
            ctl00$MainContent$AdvancedSearch$AdvRangeStartEndTextbox: "* Please use a proper Date Format (YYYY-MM-DD)"
        },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-horizontal').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-horizontal').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I just thought that I would throw in my .02 here. Client Id's do not work when in script files ( but you already knew that) because ASP.NET renders the controls (and the ID's) on the page when servicing the request for the page. I have found 2 ways around this and have been able to add code to my script files.

If you are using .NET 4.0 or higher you can use `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the element which will cause the rendered control to maintain the ID that you assigned it in the markup. You can use this per control, at the page level, and application level in the web.config.  This makes it much easier to find it with jQuery in your script files. This would be the preferred way to do it.

If you are using an older version of .NET where ClientIDMode is not available you can use an "ends with" selector with jQuery like this `$('input[id$="myServerId"]')` to look for your item with its ID property being at the end of the rendered id from ASP.NET.

Comment: That's interesting because I had tried that, I'm using 4.0 but I couldn't get it to work but perhaps something else was going on as well..  Thanx for confirming this should work though.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is pretty old and most people aren't even using usercontrols much anymore, but I've had to do it here after moving some code in an older application from a page to a usercontrol in order to reuse it somewhere else, and I've had to deal with this. So just in case someone else has to deal with this, here is what I ended up doing:

```
function convertUserControlValidationRules($container, rules, msgs) {
  var association = {},
    newRules = {},
    newMsgs = {};

  for (var key in rules) {
    var name = "";
    if (association.hasOwnProperty(key))
        name = association[key];
    else {
        name = $container.find("#" + key).attr("name");
        association[key] = name;
    }

    newRules[name] = rules[key];
    if (msgs.hasOwnProperty(key))
        newMsgs[name] = msgs[key];
  }

  return { rules: newRules, messages: newMsgs };
}
```

Where `$container` is the form's jQuery object, and rules/msgs are the original rules/messages. Obviously, you will need to use this with a `ClientIDMode="Static"` declaration in your usercontrol.

A small example of usage here, would be:

```
var ucRules = convertUserControlValidationRules($form, { txtDate: { required: true }}, { txtDate: { required: "Please enter the date!" }});
$form.validate({ rules: ucRules.rules, messages: ucRules.message });
```

instead of

```
$form.validate({ 
  rules: { txtDate: { required: true }},
  messages: { txtDate: { required: "Please enter the date!" }}
});
```

very minimal code to change, mucho time saved! Hope that can help somebody!